# Can't get data via filter () in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

I am trying to find the tasks assigned to the user through this

```
router.get('/all', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const assignments_raw = await Assignment.find({listP: listP.indexOf(req.user.userId)})
    res.json(assignments_raw)
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Something went wrong, try again' })
  }
})
```

Specifically, this line should have found all the tasks that have an element corresponding to the user ID inside the listP field

```
 const assignments_raw = await Assignment.find({listP: listP.indexOf(req.user.userId)})
```

But this causes an error, why?
below is an excerpt from Mango
[image: mng]

Comment: _But this causes an error_: What error?

Comment: the logic didn't work @prasad_

Comment: What is the logic you are trying? Trying to find if the `req.user.userId` is in the array `listP`?

Comment: yes!!! @prasad_ !

Comment: See how to [Query an Array for an Element](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/#query-an-array-for-an-element).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this

```
router.get('/all', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const assignments_raw = await Assignment.find()
    let assignments = []
    assignments_raw.map(assignment => {
          if (assignment.listP.indexOf(req.user.userId) !== -1) {
              assignments.push(assignment)
          }


        }
        )
    res.json(assignments)
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Something went wrong, try again' })
  }
})
```